# Translated documents to apply for a UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, translations

I have a temporary visa in France and I am intending to apply for a UK Standard Visitor visa. I know that I need to translate some of my documents from French to English. Is it possible to translate those documents from French to English outside the country we are applying (France) for example my home country as long as those translations are certified translations or we can only or must translate those documents inside the country we are applying?

Thank you so much everyone in advance for your information!

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica  It does not answer my question.

Comment: @Erwin The suggested duplicate contains a link to the relevant guidance and an extract from it. Nowhere does that guidance mandate *where* a translation must be done. I recently translated a document from outside the country of application; the application was approved. It makes no sense to allow applications from any location where the applicant is legally present, only to then insist on translations from a specific location

Comment: @Traveller Thank you for your information. I just want to make sure as I am currently willing to translate some of my documents in French to English documents in my home country because I think that it will cost lower price than in France.